# How do I trickle results to the client from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

For testing I would like to create a query that trickles results back to the client.

Have it return 1 row, wait a second, return 1 row.

I tried the trivial change but it failed. (it returns a single chunk)

```
select pg_sleep(1)
union all 
select pg_sleep(1)
```

How can I craft a query that trickles results back?

Comment: You should explain more of your question, such as: What client? In SQL we access rows one at a time via a result set. So there is no need to slow down Postgres. The data is pulled by the client, not pushed to the client.

Comment: @basil I am trying to confirm my client is using libpq correctly, in particular I want to know that it is waiting on the socket multiple times and PQgetResult is called multiple times, so I want to simulate a case where the client needs to do so to behave correctly.

Comment: I was thinking of possibly using a second query to lock rows or pages. unlocking/locking a diff section each second.

Comment: Does the client [call PQsetSingleRowMode](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-single-row-mode.html) (ver >= 9.2)? Otherwise I was under the impression PQgetResult blocked until it returned all records for the given resultset, so you'd only expect it to be called twice (with the second call returning null).

Comment: Great point @TimStone I still managed to crash the pg gem with a locking trick though, something is fishy

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are trying to test slow connections between the database and the client.  If this is the case, I would not recommend trickling data row-by-row, instead just throttle the whole connection.  You should be able to find a throttling proxy that suits your needs pretty quickly.  A quick google search turned up the following for me:

https://github.com/mistakster/throttle-proxy